# Rails 5.2.3 Blob Error with Active Storage when create file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm using rails 5.2.3 and I am trying to use ActiveStorage for a new scaffolded agenda. I have followed this [tutorial](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)

I want to save files locally on the filesystem.

At the moment when I want to create a new object by web form, I get the following error:

> Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable, expected
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob/analyzable.rb
>   to define it

From Mail-log:

> [ERROR] blogs create (NoMethodError) "Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`:\nundefined method `fetch' for n

And when I refresh the page I get:

> undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass

#### My Definitions

**model**:

```
has_one_attached :image
```

**controller**:

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
  .
  .
end

def blog_params
  params.require(:blog).permit(:name, :audit_comment, :image)
end
```

**views**:

```
= simple_form_for(blog) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, label: 'Name'

    = f.file_field :image

  = f.input :audit_comment
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

In **development.rb**:

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

What have I missed? 
I've runned `rails active_storage:install` and migrations as this setup [suggested](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup)

When I whole new rails app it works fine.